# IE9 won't play video tag a red cross appear asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer-9, html5-video

I have been NOT able to play video on IE9. I am developing on Visual Studio 2010 so I am using Cassini. Chrome plays the video very well but on IE a red cross appear. I read around a lot and most problem seem because of MIME configuration. So I put

```
    <staticContent>
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
    </staticContent>
```

into web.config under system.webserver and use IIS Express to run the site instead of CAssini. And this is when I got this error.

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Copying an pasting the text of the error would be more useful than an enormous screenshot scaled so that none of the text is readable.

Comment: Obviously there's already a MIME map for mp4, supposedly in the IIS settings, so I guess that when using IIS you won't have to add the mimeMap to the configuration.

Comment: Thanks to robertc .. if you click Ctrl key on your keyboard and scroll up using your mouse .. you will be able to see it clearly .. 

Thanks to KBoek .. I am trying to add that setting coz IE9 natively wwon't play the video just appearing a red cross .. can you think of anything else for the problem ?

Comment: Satan's browser (aka IE) struggles with any modern code including the new video/audio elements. It's like adjusting rabbit ear antennas for a TV. You'll probably find the problem lies in how the video was encoded and the magic formula for making things just right. Something no other browser has a problem with and it's something I thought I had fixed myself but just found out I, too, was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From more research and reading ... I tweak web.config abit more and now IE9 can play my videos ... Magic :D

```
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <staticContent>
          <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      </staticContent>
```

Code Behind

```
    Dim FileName As String = dt.Rows(0).Item("FileName")
    Dim Location As String = dt.Rows(0).Item("RESLOCATION")
    Dim str As New StringBuilder
    str.Append("<video width='320' height='240' controls='controls'>")
    str.Append("<source src='")
    str.Append(Location & FileName)
    str.Append("' type='video/mp4' />")
    str.Append("</video>")
    videodiv.InnerHtml = str.ToString
```

Aspx

```
    <div id="videodiv" runat="server"></div>
```

Comment: your original problem then: you defined the mime-type twice, 1) globally (or at least on a higher level) and 2) locally. IIS unfortunately is too stupid to handle that and outputs a 5xx error. for (1) this could have been pre-defined by IIS. it's sometimes worth checking the GUI for IIS instead of just writing config-files. It would have shown all defined types

Comment: THanks Jorn, it seems like IIS already know this MIME type but I have no idea why the video won't play if I remove this code from the web.config.

Comment: have you checked which content-type header is send with the mp4 files? you can do this in chrome or firefox: hit f12 to open the dev-console/firebug; go to the network-tab; open the website that tries to load the mp4; look for the video in the list of loaded files and click on it. maybe iis returns video/mpeg instead of video/mp4. that would cause ie9 to fail (happened to me). if so, update the mime-types on server-level (easy via GUI, dunno about config files) that should update all your websites hosted by that server